# rbinom function in r, trying to get the probability

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate the probability of a family having two children and they both being girls using the `rbinom` function. I am trying to get the probability of this question and the rbinom does not give the probability it just gives random values. How can I get it to probability?

Comment: Try `dbinom` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3/topics/Binomial

Comment: I specifically have to use the rbinom function for this assignment. @cookesd

Comment: hint: for the parameters in `rbinom`; I  assume the `prob`ability of a girl is 0.5. And set `size` to 2 as this allows the states 0,1 or 2 girls.

Comment: In that case you can generate a bunch of random variable and see the percent of times your desired case is true. user20650 gave a good hint on the probabilities

Comment: I find it odd that you are asked to used `rbinom` to "estimate the probability". You have to supply `rbinom` with the probability...

Comment: Just what the question states, the exact question states "Using simulation, estimate the prob" but he says to use rbinom above the question. @BenNorris

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `rbinom` is

```
rbinom(
       n, # The number of samples (or iterations if you like)
       size, # The size of the sample
       prob # The probability of "success" for your definition of success
       )
```

If you assume the probability of having a girl is 50% (it's not - there are a number of confounding variables and the actual birth ratio of girls to boys is closer to 100:105), then you can calculate the outcome of one "trial" with a sample size of 2 children.

```
rbinom(1, 2, 0.5)
```

You will get an outcome of 0, 1, or 2 girls (it is random). This does not give you the probability that they are both girls. You have to complete multiple "trials".

Here is an example with `n = 10`. I am using `set.seed` to provide a specific initial state to the RNG to make the results reproducible.

```
set.seed(100)
num_girls <- rbinom(10, 2, 0.5)
```

You can do a little trick to find out how many times there are two girls.

```
sum(num_girls == 2) # Does the comparison and adds; TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0
1
```

So there are 1/10 times when you get two girls. The number of trials is not enough to approach the true probability yet, but you should get the idea.